# Is Underlining Available as a Markup Format

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can text be formatted as underline?  If not, can this feature be added?

Comment: I wish there were. Or possibly some highlighter-like highlighting. People use italics, bold, and double-quotes to try to refer to strings of text that themselves might have italics, bold, or quotes. Yes, one can refer to a block of text by offsetting it as a block quotation. But there is currently no good way, that I know of, to highlight strings of text in context. (And, yes, if underlining or highlighting were added then the problem I mention would be raised for text that already has underlining or highlighting...;-) Still, it would be helpful, IMO.)

Comment: Underlining is the traditional way to indicate a hyperlink on the web, and so its use for any other kind of emphasis is a big no-no in user experience circles. Besides, underlining often substituted in earlier days for italic, bold, small-cap, and other formatting options that were not available on typewriters— a situation much-improved nowadays.

Comment: @choster Your point that underlining is used for hyperlinks is a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no underlining markup for markdown. The `<u>` tag doesn't work either, so there is no way to underline on EL&U.

I cannot answer the other part of your question, as I'm not a Stack Exchange developer, but there is a [meta meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152160/underline-and-color-picker) that covers it.

It essentially says, "no."

Comment: ..........            _Thanks!_